# MongoDB get elements before specific Id with limit and after with limit

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I've got a difficult task. I've wasted a lot of time. I am want to get all documents before document with specific ID with limitation and after this document with limitation, in one query. How can I do that?

Comment: By the specific ID you mean that you have an ID field which can be sorted or using the internal _id of the mongo document ?

Comment: Internal _id. I am geting left limitation, id, and right limitation from controller as query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is an `ObjectId` and it contains a timestamp in it, so you may be able to get this timestamp via `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` and create a query based on it.

See [BSON types - ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid).